# How do I prove that this operator is no compact and limited?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A : l_2 \to l_2$:
$$
Ax = (x_1, \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3}, \dots)
$$

How to prove that a given operator is bounded and no compact, but  $\|Ae_n\| \to 0$ where $e_n$ is a standard basis.

Could you please give me a hint on how to start solving such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

By [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy's_inequality), one has
\begin{align*}
\|Ax\|_{2}^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n}}{n}\right)^{2}\leq 2^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}^{2}=4\|x\|_{2}^{2},
\end{align*}
so $\|A\|\leq 2<\infty$, $A$ is bounded.

For the compactness, one can check that $A$ is self-adjoint, if it were compact, then one of $\|A\|$ or $-\|A\|$ must be an eigenvalue of $A$. Anyway, we have $\|A\|>1$, and if we let $\lambda:=\|A\|$ or $-\|A\|$, one can check that $Ax=\lambda x$ has no solution for $x\ne 0$.